# parallax for uitable view does not work , ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parallax

There are lots of tutorial on how to do the parallex on Ios and I found one article at [here](http://rowboatrevolution.com/2012/02/uitableview-parallax-background-a-la-path/).

The main idea of this article is to make a header of table view transparently so that you can see thru the image which is inserted below the tableview :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create an empty table header view with small bottom border view
    UIView *tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 180.0)];
    UIView *blackBorderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, 179.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 1.0)];
    blackBorderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0 green: 0.0 blue: 0.0 alpha: 0.8];
    [tableHeaderView addSubview: blackBorderView];
    [blackBorderView release];

    _tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView;
    [tableHeaderView release];

    // Create the underlying imageview and offset it
    _headerImageYOffset = -150.0;
    _headerImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"header-image.png"]];
    CGRect headerImageFrame = _headerImage.frame;
    headerImageFrame.origin.y = _headerImageYOffset;
    _headerImage.frame = headerImageFrame;
    [self.view insertSubview: _headerImage belowSubview: _tableView];
}
```

I did give it a try and it the code does not work on me. I think we cant make a header of table view transparently unless we make a whole table transparently...
Have you ever tried it and any thoughts about this. All comments are welcomed here

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial, it will show you how to customize any view with the drawrect method:http://www.raywenderlich.com/32925/core-graphics-tutorial-shadows-and-gloss

Comment: Have you tried with the clear color of whole UITableView?

Comment: Yeh that rowboat sample didn't work for me either, I just got my image full screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through that tutorial before and it worked perfect.  I can't remember if I had to make the table background clear, but what's the problem with making it clear?  Just change your cell backgrounds to the background color you want in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

Comment: I am adding `self.tableView.tableHeaderView.backgroundColor  =   [UIColor clearColor];`but it does not work.. what I am getting is like [this](http://cl.ly/OvS3).

Comment: try making self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor] where you init the table and then add - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];}

Comment: oh I get it right now. the whole idea is to set a table transparently it this will make `tableViewHeader` and `cells` transparently as well then we have to change the `contentView` background so that we can see the effect. It does a trick. By the way, `cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]` should be `cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]`

Answer (score 4):

I once used [APParallaxHeader](https://github.com/apping/APParallaxHeader) Library and it worked like a charm. I advice you to give it a try ;)

Comment: yup i went thru and it worked perfect.I am trying another technique for the same effect but getting stuck at here.